# Max-height and max-width for divs with dynamic backgrounds?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a code responsible for cropping image and saving its cropped areas in a list of divs. Each of these divs represents each of the cropped images. But the problem is - I dont want them to be so huge, I want them to have `fixed` height and width, e.g. max 100x100px.

Codesandbox with working image cropping: **https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-frost-0b5tt**
Code revelant to cropping logic:

```
const width = pos.w + "px";
const height = pos.h + "px";
const marginLeft = - pos.x + "px";
const marginTop = - pos.y + "px";

return (
  <div
    key={i}
    style={{
      width: width,
      height: height,
      backgroundSize: "400px 300px",
      backgroundPosition: `top ${marginTop} left ${marginLeft}`,
      backgroundImage: "url('https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/puppy-dog.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=400')"
    }}
  />
);
```

You will see that image cropping works great, however newly created images have dynamic height and width.

**Question**: How to make these newly created divs to have fixed width and height, but without destroying it? Thanks!

### Edit: New link added (the old one was missing styles)

The goal is to make the children (cropped images) to have static height and width, but keep the background image in correct position. But seems like im too stopid to do it by myself

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @Dominic Chrome for sure :P

Comment: @Paulie_D Can't use stack snippet since `Jcrop` lib doesn't have a CDN link to include in snippet - had to use codesandbox.

Comment: if you cannot create a stack snippet, you can add the relevant code to the question itself. The goal is to _make sure your question can be understood without visiting these websites_

Comment: It looks like your manually setting them to 300x400... I am not seeing anyway to generate a new image to test what you are talking about

Comment: @TaylorBelk `300x400` is the parent image where user can crop smaller parts of it. The goal is to make the children (cropped parts) to have static height and width, but keep the background in proper position

Comment: I think it needs an image transformation algorithm. Let's assume you want to crop a square of 200x200 and you want to project it on 100x100

You first of all need to know the area that you want to show and transform it to max-height or max-width dimensions by keeping the proper ratio

Comment: what didn't work well to you with my answer?

Comment: @Xesenix Its nice :D But not the best solution in answers

Comment: strange when it covers both other cases but as you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix both height and width, the previews will look distorted. So I would recommend
only fixing the height.

```
  const fixedHeight = 100;
  const zoom = fixedHeight / pos.h;
  const backgroundWidth = 400 * zoom;
  const backgroundHeight = 300 * zoom;
  const width = pos.w * zoom;
  const height = fixedHeight;
  const marginLeft = -pos.x * zoom;
  const marginTop = -pos.y * zoom;
```

See results in this [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-chaplygin-t8141).

Comment: Based on your idea I have created my solution. You can actually determine which axis to use for zooming by choosing biggest zoom between axis.

Answer (score 3):

The following change within your render function will create a 100px square centered on the selection's center point, or as close as possible keeping within the image limits (I'm not sure how to reference the original image's width & height from here).

```
...
const previews = crops.map(({ pos }, i) => {
  const width = 100 + "px";
  const height = 100 + "px";
  let margx = (pos.w / 2) - 50 + pos.x;
  let margy = (pos.h / 2) - 50 + pos.y;
  if(margx < 0) margx = 0;
  if(margy < 0) margy = 0;
  // this needs origional image width & height (400,300) to get max values
  const maxx = 400-100;
  const maxy = 300-100;
  if(margx > maxx) margx = maxx;
  if(margy > maxy) margy = maxy;
  const marginLeft = - margx + "px";
  const marginTop = - margy + "px";

  return (
    <div
...
```

Comment: Based on your centering idea you can additionally zoom in/out if its required.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose something in between solutions proposed by @MunimMunna and @ArleighHix improving both solutions.
[See result](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-morning-1r1d9?fontsize=14)

```
// setup base image size
const imageBaseWidth = 400;
const imageBaseHeight = 300;
// choose thumbnail size and aspect ratio
const thumbHeight = 100;
const thumbWidth = 200;
// we check which axis needs to be filled to border
const zoomX = thumbWidth / pos.w;
const zoomY = thumbHeight / pos.h;
// you can improve it further by defining max zoom in level so that thumbnails don't show ugly pixels
// just use additional zoom = Math.min(zoom, maxZoom) and some more logic for handling min max margin offset so it wont go outside image bounds
const zoom = Math.max(zoomX, zoomY);
// scaling base image to best fit available space
const backgroundWidth = imageBaseWidth * zoom;
const backgroundHeight = imageBaseHeight * zoom;
// calculate offset to top left corner of biggest rect in selected region that keeps target aspect ratio
const marginLeft = thumbWidth / 2 - (pos.w / 2 + pos.x) * zoom;
const marginTop = thumbHeight / 2 - (pos.h / 2 + pos.y) * zoom;

return (
  <div
    className="preview"
    key={i}
    style={{
      width: thumbWidth + "px",
      height: thumbHeight + "px",
      backgroundSize: `${backgroundWidth}px ${backgroundHeight}px`,
      backgroundPosition: `top ${marginTop}px left ${marginLeft}px`,
      backgroundImage: "url('https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/puppy-dog.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=400')"
    }}
  />
);
```

It chooses bigest posible region inside selection that keeps aspect ratio of targeted thumbnails and zooms in on it if required. You can setup target thumbnails size with `fixedHeight`, `fixedWidth`

Comment: Your answer should state that it's an improvement to another answer including authors name.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a rewrite without the jcrop library, to have better access to all the props, size, positioning etc.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7ubxaa

Comment: Hahaha, nice! I like it!